# Mysql SUM - how do I avoid sum the same stuff multiple times

Tags: mysql, sum

I'm trying to generate an age balance of debitors, but I'm having touble using MySQL SUM when the I have to take balance history into account.

I can get the current balance of the customer by:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM `transaction` WHERE customer_id = 1
```

At first when I wanted to get an old balance - ie. how the balance looked 2011-08-31 I thought the following was enough:

```
SELECT SUM(balance) FROM `transaction` WHERE customer_id = 1 AND posted <= '2011-08-31'
```

But the above doesn't take any balancing history which has occurred since 2011-09-01 until now into account. I've stored all balancing history in a table. So If a customer (partly) pays the bill 2011-09-06 then the tables would look something like the following:

Transactions:

```
id | text    | amount | balance | posted
 1 | Invoice | 100.00 |   20.00 | 2011-08-14
 2 | Payment |  80.00 |    0.00 | 2011-09-06
```

Balance history:

```
id | source | destination | amount | created
 1 |      1 |           2 |  80.00 | 2011-09-06
```

I thought I've solved it with the following query:

```
SELECT customer_id, SUM(balance)+SUM(IFNULL(bh_source.amount, 0))-SUM(IFNULL(bh_destination.amount, 0)) AS `current_balance`
FROM `transaction`
LEFT JOIN balancehistory AS bh_source ON `transaction`.id = bh_source.source AND DATE(bh_source.created) > "2011-08-31"
LEFT JOIN balancehistory AS bh_destination ON `transaction`.id = bh_destination.destination AND DATE(bh_destination.created) > "2011-08-31"
WHERE posted <= "2011-08-31"
GROUP BY customer_id
```

But when the balancing history becomes more complex ie. like the following - it fails:

Transactions:

```
id | text              | amount  | balance | posted
 1 | Invoice           |  100.00 |    0.00 | 2011-08-14
 2 | Payment           |  -80.00 |    0.00 | 2011-09-06
 3 | Payment cancelled |   80.00 |    0.00 | 2011-09-08
 4 | VISA              | -100.00 |    0.00 | 2011-10-10
```

Balance history:

```
id | source | destination |  amount | created
 1 |      1 |           2 |   80.00 | 2011-09-06
 2 |      2 |           1 |  -80.00 | 2011-09-08
 3 |      3 |           2 |   80.00 | 2011-09-08
 4 |      1 |           4 | -100.00 | 2011-10-10
```

I've been banging my head against a wall for a long time now and hope you guys have some suggestions. The table structure **isn't** locked so if need be it can be altered.

Thanks.

**Update:**

I now see that I have simplified my problem too much - but thanks anyway Tom.
I'm not (only) interested in a current total but instead I want to group amounts based on their due date. I'm trying to create a table which shows how much over due payments are. Ie. between 0-30 days, 30-90 days etc.:

Age balance (multiple SQL results using different reference dates on the following data):

```
reference  | before due | 0-30 days | 30-90 days
2011-08-31 |     233.79 |      0.00 |       0.00
2011-09-02 |       0.00 |      0.00 |       0.00
2011-09-07 |       0.00 |    233.79 |       0.00
2011-10-18 |     100.00 |      0.00 |     233.79
2011-10-25 |       0.00 |    100.00 |     233.79
2011-10-28 |       0.00 |      0.00 |       0.00
```

Transactions:

```
id | customer_id | text             | amount  | balance | posted     | due
 1 |           1 | Invoice 1        |  233.79 |    0.00 | 2011-08-17 | 2011-09-01
 2 |           1 | Payment 1        | -233.79 |    0.00 | 2011-09-01 | 2011-09-01
 3 |           1 | Payment rejected |  233.79 |    0.00 | 2011-09-06 | 2011-09-06
 4 |           1 | Reminder         |  100.00 |    0.00 | 2011-09-14 | 2011-09-23
 5 |           1 | Payment 2        | -333.79 |    0.00 | 2011-09-23 | 2011-09-23
```

Balance history:

```
id | source | destination | amount | created
 1 |      1 |           2 | 233.79 | 2011-09-05
 2 |      2 |           1 | 233.79 | 2011-09-09
 3 |      3 |           2 | 233.79 | 2011-09-09
 4 |      1 |           5 | 233.79 | 2011-10-26
 5 |      4 |           5 | 100.00 | 2011-10-26
```

Here is an example of the SQL I thought would find the age balance for a specific date:

```
SELECT SUM(IF("2011-08-31" <= due, balance, 0))
     + SUM(IF("2011-08-31" <= due, IFNULL(bh_source.amount, 0), 0))
     - SUM(IF("2011-08-31" <= due, IFNULL(bh_destination.amount, 0), 0)) AS before_due,
       SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 0 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)), balance, 0))
     + SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 0 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)), IFNULL(bh_source.amount, 0), 0))
     - SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 0 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)), IFNULL(bh_destination.amount, 0), 0)) AS 0_30_days,
       SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 90 DAY)), balance, 0))
     + SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 90 DAY)), IFNULL(bh_source.amount, 0), 0))
     - SUM(IF("2011-08-31" >  DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 30 DAY)) AND
              "2011-08-31" <= DATE(ADDDATE(due, INTERVAL 90 DAY)), IFNULL(bh_destination.amount, 0), 0)) AS 30_90_days
FROM `transaction`
LEFT JOIN balancehistory AS bh_source ON `transaction`.id = bh_source.source AND DATE(bh_source.created) > "2011-08-31"
LEFT JOIN balancehistory AS bh_destination ON `transaction`.id = bh_destination.destination AND DATE(bh_destination.created) > "2011-08-31"
WHERE posted <= "2011-08-31"
GROUP BY customer_id
```

But it doesn't work as intended. Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bit more joy if you split your invoice and payment transactions into two separate tables. For example:

```
invoice
id | customer_id  | invoice_description  | amount | postedOn
 1 |     1        | Services Invoice     | 100.00 | 2011-08-14 12:35:01

payment
id |  customer_id | invoice_id | payment_type        | amount  | madeOn
 1 |      1       |      1     | Payment             | -80.00  | 2011-09-08 08:09:12
 1 |      1       |      1     | Payment Cancelled   |  80.00  | 2011-09-08 08:12:34
 1 |      1       |      1     | VISA Payment        | -100.00 | 2011-10-10 17:22:54
```

You should then be able to derive the current balance for a given customer at any point in time by getting the sum of all invoices issued to them up to that point in time and subtracting the payments received up to that point in time for the same invoices. Hence:

```
select customer_id,sum(invoice_balance) as totalBalance
from
(
select i.customer_id, i.id as invoice_id,
i.amount - sum(ifnull(p.amount,0)) as invoice_balance
from invoice i
left join (select p.invoice_id,p.amount from payment  where p.madeOn > '2011-09-01') p
on p.invoice_id = i.id
where i.postedOn > '2011-09-01'
group by i.customer_id, i.id, i.amount
) t group by customer_id;
```

I have omitted the join on customer_id on purpose because I guess it is possible (however unlikely) for a payment to be made by a different customer to the customer to whom the invoice was originally issued. Taking it on a bit further you may want to normalise out the payment_type column on the payment table to a paymentType table or something similar.

Comment: Your answer is correct based on my initial question but I realised that my question was wrong :-S